# How to display multiple data lines in C3 timeseries chart for the given JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, c3.js, timeserieschart

I want to generate multiple `timeseries` chart in C3. My data in `JSON` looks like this below. I want `"unixTS"` on `x-axis` and for each ID, I want to display line with its `tempValue` on `Y-axis`. How do I display for each ID, like for `ID 1, ID 2, ID 3` with their respective `tempValue`. Finally I need to have 3 linesin the chart for `ID 1 , ID 2 and ID 3` with their tempValues.Also the unix time stamp is unique for each ID, Please suggest me.

```
[
 {"ID":"1","unixTS":1489481279257,"tempValue":24.71},   
 {"ID":"1","unixTS":1489481284262,"tempValue":17.72}, 
 {"ID":"1","unixTS":1489481289268,"tempValue":15.69},
 {"ID":"2","unixTS":1489481289268,"tempValue":15.69},
 {"ID":"2","unixTS":1489481289268,"tempValue":15.69},
 {"ID":"3","unixTS":1489481289268,"tempValue":17.69},
 {"ID":"3","unixTS":1489481289268,"tempValue":15.89}
]
```